# What is the equivalent command of 'minikube addons list' in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, add-on

The command 'kubectl addons list' throws an error:
Error: unknown command "addons" for "kubectl"
Run 'kubectl --help' for usage.

The command 'kubectl plugin list' seems to return something different.
error: unable to find any kubectl plugins in your PATH

Thanks

Comment: Check out Krew.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  [`minikube addons`](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/addons/) does a couple of things that are specific to Minikube, and other Kubernetes installations would do these in different ways.

Comment: Thanks David. I am new to k8s, and trying to follow the tutorials that are for the minikube. I've installed k8s.

I wanted to enable the ingress addons. I think I need to create a yml file with 'kind: Ingress' in k8s, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as you have stated that you want to enable ingress in your kubernetes cluster:

it works differently on full-blown k8s than in minikube.

in kubernetes, you will need to deploy and configure and ingress controller. having done that the ingress controller will then watch resources of type "ingress".

check the official documentation [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/) for a list of supported ingress controllers and [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/) for an example how to deploy the nginx ingress controller